# How can I resolve error when trying to launch instance on Amazon RDS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, amazon-web-services

I'm using the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2013 to attempt to launch a new instance on Amazon RDS.  I get through the wizard for creating the new instance and after clicking finish, there is a delay, and then a message appears saying:

> Error launching DB instance: DB Security Groups can only be associated with VPC DB Instances using API version 2012-01-15 through 2012-09-17.

Launching different types of instances (SQL Server SE vs MySQL) doesn't seem to help, nor does selecting different versions of the platforms (SQL Server 2008 vs 2012).  The only thing that gets it to go through is unchecking the box for "default" in the DB Security Groups area.  However, I feel like something is going on here that shouldn't be happening.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can resolve it other than by not setting a default security group?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your AWS account recently, you will be using a VPC by default.

It sounds like the API the plugin is trying to use hasn't been updated.  The latest version is 1.5.6, and looking at the history it seems like some of these features were added in 1.5.0.

Comment: I had exact same problem, and I couldn't crete new db instance from VS. So I went to aws console -> RDS and created it there.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it! Since I couldn't use the API that the VS 2013 plugin uses, I had to manually add my IP to the Security Group created for my Elastic Beanstalk.

1. Go to the [console, ec2's security groups configuration](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#SecurityGroups:securityGroups=vpc-security-groups)
2. Find the one which description matches your Beanstalk (e.g.: *Security Group created for Beanstalk Environment to give access to RDS instances*)
3. Hit **Inbound**, **Edit** and add a new rule for *All Traffic* (I guess HTTP should be enough, but just in case).
4. In **Source**, select **My IP** and Save.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, just a workaround. This solution allows traffic to come from anywhere and touch the database, essentially disabling security groups

Comment: @yasgur99 no, it only allows traffic from your public IP. It does not allow traffic to come from anywhere. The answer also states that `HTTP should be enough, but just in case`.