# DB Security Groups can only be associated with VPC DB Instances using API versions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds

I have this code below to create a RDS instance in aws:

```
import boto.rds

REGION="us-east-1"
INSTANCE_TYPE="db.t1.micro"
ID = "MySQL-db-instance-database-test2"
USERNAME="root"
PASSWORD = "pass"
DB_PORT = 3306
DB_SIZE = 5
DB_ENGINE = "MySQL5.1"
DB_NAME = "databasetest2"
SECGROUP_HANDLE="default"

print "Connecting to RDS"

conn = boto.rds.connect_to_region(REGION)

print "Creating a RDS Instance"

instance = conn.create_dbinstance(ID, DB_SIZE, INSTANCE_TYPE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, port=DB_PORT, engine=DB_ENGINE,db_name=DB_NAME, security_groups = [SECGROUP_HANDLE],)

print instance
```

But I am having always this error related to security groups:

> DB Security Groups can only be associated with VPC DB Instances using API versions 2012-01-15 through 2012-09-17.

Can anyone please help solve this issue?

If I use vpc_security_groups instead of security_groups Im having:

```
 <Message>Invalid security group , groupId= f, u, d, t, e, a, l, groupName=.</Message>
```

Comment: It would help to see the stack trace and the exact error message. Based on  [this similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639947/how-can-i-resolve-error-when-trying-to-launch-instance-on-amazon-rds) I have a hunch you're leaving off a bit of your error message (i.e. some particular API versions)...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I forget to put the full message, but now I updated the question with that!

Answer (score 14):

RDS instances in VPCs can not be members of RDS security groups. Instead, a RDS within a VPC should be in a VPC security group. In boto, use the `vpc_security_groups` parameter (with the VPC security group ID as its value) rather the `security_groups` parameter. See also the [boto RDS docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds.html) for `create_dbinstance()`.

Comment: Upaang's answer is also interesting. You might use version 2 instead, in which case `create_dbinstance()` remains the same function but the `vpc_security_groups` parameter has changed to `vpc_security_group_ids`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im not understanding why Im having this vpc error. Im not using any vpc, and I dont have nothing in my question code relative to vpc, only the error Im having. But I tried use vpc_security_groups instead of security_groups but dont works!

Comment: I also Im having this: TypeError: create_dbinstance() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vpc_security_group_ids'

Answer (score 3):

Boto is migrating RDSConnection from version 1 to version 2. You can check [this](http:////http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrations/rds_v1_to_v2.html) - 
Earlier we could have got all the db_instances using `get_all_dbinstances()`but now we can only fetch using `describe_db_instances()`. 
Try using `vpc_security_group()`.
The official doc for new version of RDS, i.e. RDS2 is [here](http:////http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds2.html).

Answer (score 0):

this *may* work. I'm not getting the error with my script but my client is. I'm guessing it's because I have a default VPC security group, which AWS is silently using, and he does not.

```
boto.rds.RDSConnection.APIVersion = '2012-09-17'
```

the idea being that, since this API is within (at the end of) the specified range, the error will not apply.

I got the idea from https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2923